# Read response JSON from EAN API with PHP - Loop

Tags: php, json

I am trying to build an application that searches through a Response JSON from the Expidia API.

When I use this method it works fine:

```
<form name="search_form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
<label><span class="label">Town:</span>
<input type="text" id="search_town" name="search_town"></label>
<br><br><input class="Send" type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    SearchTown();
}

function SearchTown()
{
$search_town = $_POST['search_town'];
$no_requests = "1";

$url    = "http://dev.api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55505&apiKey=r662e63dr8tkvh9ttqjmsev8&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&xml=%3CHotelListRequest%3E%3Ccity%3E".$search_town."%3C/city%3E%3CarrivalDate%3E08/01/2014%3C/arrivalDate%3E%3CdepartureDate%3E08/03/2014%3C/departureDate%3E%3CRoomGroup%3E%3CRoom%3E%3CnumberOfAdults%3E2%3C/numberOfAdults%3E%3C/Room%3E%3C/RoomGroup%3E%3CnumberOfResults%3E".$no_requests."%3C/numberOfResults%3E%3CsupplierCacheTolerance%3EMED_ENHANCED%3C/supplierCacheTolerance%3E%3C/HotelListRequest%3E";
$result = file_get_contents($url);


$data = json_decode($result);

    print_r($data->HotelListResponse->HotelList->HotelSummary->name);
}
?>
```

It gives me the Hotel in the City I type in. So this works fine

In the URL Request I just searched for 1 reply, but obviously I would like to get back a few Hotels.

I tried this:

```
<form name="search_form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
<label><span class="label">Town:</span>
<input type="text" id="search_town" name="search_town"></label>
<br><br><input class="Send" type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    SearchTown();
}

function SearchTown()
{
$search_town = $_POST['search_town'];
$no_requests = "2";

$url    = "http://dev.api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55505&apiKey=r662e63dr8tkvh9ttqjmsev8&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&xml=%3CHotelListRequest%3E%3Ccity%3E".$search_town."%3C/city%3E%3CarrivalDate%3E08/01/2014%3C/arrivalDate%3E%3CdepartureDate%3E08/03/2014%3C/departureDate%3E%3CRoomGroup%3E%3CRoom%3E%3CnumberOfAdults%3E2%3C/numberOfAdults%3E%3C/Room%3E%3C/RoomGroup%3E%3CnumberOfResults%3E".$no_requests."%3C/numberOfResults%3E%3CsupplierCacheTolerance%3EMED_ENHANCED%3C/supplierCacheTolerance%3E%3C/HotelListRequest%3E";
$result = file_get_contents($url);


$data = json_decode($result);

for ($i = 1; $i <= $no_requests; $i++) {
    print_r($data->HotelListResponse->HotelList->HotelSummary->name[$i]);
}
}
?>
```

It gives me the notice:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\vhi_test\testing2.php on line 34
```

I have tried a million different approaches and just can not seem to get more than ONE name out of the Response. Please, can anybody help? Much much appreciated.

Edit:
Here are sample responses for both single and multiple results, respectively.

```
{"HotelListResponse":{"customerSessionId":"0ABAAAB2-1097-6F91-4712-BDAD2ED90D22","numberOfRoomsRequested":1,"moreResultsAvailable":true,"cacheKey":"-7610976f:1471bdad2ed:-d20","cacheLocation":"10.186.170.178:7300","HotelList":{"@size":"1","@activePropertyCount":"142","HotelSummary":{"@order":"0","hotelId":126952,"name":"Cleveland Marriott Downtown at Key Center","address1":"127 Public Sq","city":"Cleveland","stateProvinceCode":"OH","postalCode":44114,"countryCode":"US","airportCode":"CLE","supplierType":"E","propertyCategory":1,"hotelRating":3.5,"confidenceRating":52,"amenityMask":16818307,"tripAdvisorRating":4.5,"locationDescription":"Near Quicken Loans Arena","shortDescription":"<p><b>Property Location<\\/b> <br \\/>With a stay at Cleveland Marriott Downtown at Key Center, you'll be centrally located in Cleveland, steps from Old Stone Church and Key Tower. This hotel is within","highRate":159,"lowRate":159,"rateCurrencyCode":"USD","latitude":41.50044,"longitude":-81.69424,"proximityDistance":3.4120276,"proximityUnit":"MI","hotelInDestination":true,"thumbNailUrl":"\\/hotels\\/1000000\\/30000\\/23200\\/23199\\/23199_66_t.jpg","deepLink":"http:\\/\\/travel.ian.com\\/index.jsp?pageName=hotAvail&cid=55505&hotelID=126952&mode=2&numberOfRooms=1&room-0-adult-total=2&room-0-child-total=0&arrivalMonth=7&arrivalDay=1&departureMonth=7&departureDay=3&showInfo=true&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD","RoomRateDetailsList":{"RoomRateDetails":{"roomTypeCode":30940,"rateCode":202960472,"maxRoomOccupancy":4,"quotedRoomOccupancy":2,"minGuestAge":0,"roomDescription":"Deluxe Room - Advance Purchase*","currentAllotment":0,"propertyAvailable":true,"propertyRestricted":false,"expediaPropertyId":23199,"rateKey":"0ABAAAB2-1097-6F91-4712-BDAD2ED90D1F","RateInfo":{"@priceBreakdown":"true","@promo":"false","@rateChange":"false","ChargeableRateInfo":{"@averageBaseRate":"159.0","@averageRate":"159.0","@commissionableUsdTotal":"318.0","@currencyCode":"USD","@maxNightlyRate":"159.0","@nightlyRateTotal":"318.0","@surchargeTotal":"62.1","@total":"380.1","NightlyRatesPerRoom":{"@size":"2","NightlyRate":[{"@baseRate":"159.0","@rate":"159.0","@promo":"false"},{"@baseRate":"159.0","@rate":"159.0","@promo":"false"}]},"Surcharges":{"@size":"1","Surcharge":{"@type":"TaxAndServiceFee","@amount":"62.1"}}}}}}}}}}

{"HotelListResponse":{"customerSessionId":"0ABAAAB0-E70B-AC91-4712-BD8FEE3927B3","numberOfRoomsRequested":1,"moreResultsAvailable":true,"cacheKey":"-5e70bac:1471bd8fee3:27c4","cacheLocation":"10.186.170.176:7300","HotelList":{"@size":"2","@activePropertyCount":"142","HotelSummary":[{"@order":"0","hotelId":126952,"name":"Cleveland Marriott Downtown at Key Center","address1":"127 Public Sq","city":"Cleveland","stateProvinceCode":"OH","postalCode":44114,"countryCode":"US","airportCode":"CLE","supplierType":"E","propertyCategory":1,"hotelRating":3.5,"confidenceRating":52,"amenityMask":16818307,"tripAdvisorRating":4.5,"locationDescription":"Near Quicken Loans Arena","shortDescription":"<p><b>Property Location<\\/b> <br \\/>With a stay at Cleveland Marriott Downtown at Key Center, you'll be centrally located in Cleveland, steps from Old Stone Church and Key Tower. This hotel is within","highRate":159,"lowRate":159,"rateCurrencyCode":"USD","latitude":41.50044,"longitude":-81.69424,"proximityDistance":3.4120276,"proximityUnit":"MI","hotelInDestination":true,"thumbNailUrl":"\\/hotels\\/1000000\\/30000\\/23200\\/23199\\/23199_66_t.jpg","deepLink":"http:\\/\\/travel.ian.com\\/index.jsp?pageName=hotAvail&cid=55505&hotelID=126952&mode=2&numberOfRooms=1&room-0-adult-total=2&room-0-child-total=0&arrivalMonth=7&arrivalDay=1&departureMonth=7&departureDay=3&showInfo=true&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD","RoomRateDetailsList":{"RoomRateDetails":{"roomTypeCode":30940,"rateCode":202960472,"maxRoomOccupancy":4,"quotedRoomOccupancy":2,"minGuestAge":0,"roomDescription":"Deluxe Room - Advance Purchase*","currentAllotment":0,"propertyAvailable":true,"propertyRestricted":false,"expediaPropertyId":23199,"rateKey":"0ABAAAB0-E70B-AC91-4712-BD8FEE3927C5","RateInfo":{"@priceBreakdown":"true","@promo":"false","@rateChange":"false","ChargeableRateInfo":{"@averageBaseRate":"159.0","@averageRate":"159.0","@commissionableUsdTotal":"318.0","@currencyCode":"USD","@maxNightlyRate":"159.0","@nightlyRateTotal":"318.0","@surchargeTotal":"62.1","@total":"380.1","NightlyRatesPerRoom":{"@size":"2","NightlyRate":[{"@baseRate":"159.0","@rate":"159.0","@promo":"false"},{"@baseRate":"159.0","@rate":"159.0","@promo":"false"}]},"Surcharges":{"@size":"1","Surcharge":{"@type":"TaxAndServiceFee","@amount":"62.1"}}}}}}},{"@order":"1","hotelId":163227,"name":"DoubleTree by Hilton Cleveland Downtown - Lakeside","address1":"1111 Lakeside Avenue E","city":"Cleveland","stateProvinceCode":"OH","postalCode":44114,"countryCode":"US","airportCode":"CLE","supplierType":"E","propertyCategory":1,"hotelRating":3.5,"confidenceRating":52,"amenityMask":24617091,"tripAdvisorRating":4,"locationDescription":"Near Rock and Roll Hall of Fame","shortDescription":"<p><b>Property Location<\\/b> <br \\/>A stay at DoubleTree by Hilton Cleveland Downtown - Lakeside places you in the heart of Cleveland, walking distance from Cleveland Public Auditorium and Rock and","highRate":179.1,"lowRate":179.1,"rateCurrencyCode":"USD","latitude":41.50642,"longitude":-81.69018,"proximityDistance":3.3392038,"proximityUnit":"MI","hotelInDestination":true,"thumbNailUrl":"\\/hotels\\/1000000\\/20000\\/19900\\/19876\\/19876_113_t.jpg","deepLink":"http:\\/\\/travel.ian.com\\/index.jsp?pageName=hotAvail&cid=55505&hotelID=163227&mode=2&numberOfRooms=1&room-0-adult-total=2&room-0-child-total=0&arrivalMonth=7&arrivalDay=1&departureMonth=7&departureDay=3&showInfo=true&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD","RoomRateDetailsList":{"RoomRateDetails":{"roomTypeCode":345298,"rateCode":1078896,"maxRoomOccupancy":4,"quotedRoomOccupancy":2,"minGuestAge":0,"roomDescription":"Two Queen Beds Non-Smoking","currentAllotment":0,"propertyAvailable":true,"propertyRestricted":false,"expediaPropertyId":19876,"rateKey":"0ABAAAB0-E70B-AC91-4712-BD8FEE3927C6","RateInfo":{"@priceBreakdown":"true","@promo":"false","@rateChange":"false","ChargeableRateInfo":{"@averageBaseRate":"179.1","@averageRate":"179.1","@commissionableUsdTotal":"358.2","@currencyCode":"USD","@maxNightlyRate":"179.1","@nightlyRateTotal":"358.2","@surchargeTotal":"69.64","@total":"427.84","NightlyRatesPerRoom":{"@size":"2","NightlyRate":[{"@baseRate":"179.1","@rate":"179.1","@promo":"false"},{"@baseRate":"179.1","@rate":"179.1","@promo":"false"}]},"Surcharges":{"@size":"1","Surcharge":{"@type":"TaxAndServiceFee","@amount":"69.64"}}}},"ValueAdds":{"@size":"1","ValueAdd":{"@id":"2048","description":"Free Wireless Internet"}}}}}]}}}
```

Comment: What does `print_r($data);` show with `$no_requests=2`?  Also, what do you get back from a raw request to ean.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is that you're trying to access the `name` property as an array instead of `HotelSummary`.  Additionally, `HotelSummary` is only returned as an array if there is more than one result, otherwise it's an object.  This is solved by conditionally wrapping it before the loop.

The index variable `$i` in your `for` loop is initialized to `1`, but `0` is the first element of an array.  Likewise, you would have wanted to have the condition as `$i < $no_requests;`.  I replaced that with a `foreach` loop where you don't have to worry about managing the index.

```
<form name="search_form" action="" method="POST">
    <label>
        <span class="label">Town:</span>
        <input type="text" id="search_town" name="search_town" />
    </label><br />
    <br />
    <input class="Send" type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["search"]))
{
    SearchTown();
}

function SearchTown()
{
    $search_town = $_POST["search_town"];
    $no_requests = 2;

    $url = "http://dev.api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55505&apiKey=r662e63dr8tkvh9ttqjmsev8&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&xml=%3CHotelListRequest%3E%3Ccity%3E".$search_town."%3C/city%3E%3CarrivalDate%3E08/01/2014%3C/arrivalDate%3E%3CdepartureDate%3E08/03/2014%3C/departureDate%3E%3CRoomGroup%3E%3CRoom%3E%3CnumberOfAdults%3E2%3C/numberOfAdults%3E%3C/Room%3E%3C/RoomGroup%3E%3CnumberOfResults%3E".$no_requests."%3C/numberOfResults%3E%3CsupplierCacheTolerance%3EMED_ENHANCED%3C/supplierCacheTolerance%3E%3C/HotelListRequest%3E";
    $result = file_get_contents($url);


    $data = json_decode($result);

    // Make sure HotelSummary is an array - a single result does not get an array wrapper in the response.
    if (!is_array($data->HotelListResponse->HotelList->HotelSummary))
        // A simple cast using (array) won't work here - it would convert the HotelSummary object itself rather than wrapping it inside of an array.
        $data->HotelListResponse->HotelList->HotelSummary = array($data->HotelListResponse->HotelList->HotelSummary);

    foreach ($data->HotelListResponse->HotelList->HotelSummary as $i => $hotelSummary)
    {
        echo "{$i}: " . $hotelSummary->name . "<br />";
    }
}
```

When searching for Cleveland while `$no_requests` is set to `2`, the result is:

```
0: Cleveland Marriott Downtown at Key Center
1: DoubleTree by Hilton Cleveland Downtown - Lakeside
```

Performing the same search after reducing `$no_requests` to `1` results in:

```
0: Cleveland Marriott Downtown at Key Center
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me to understand JSON a lot better.